# Numpy push non-zero values down along the column

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2D numpy matrix and I want to push all non-zero values down along the columns.
I prefer a way that doesn't contain loops.
for example making this [before_matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDMag.jpg)
into this [after_matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AezUU.jpg)
Also it's important to keep the order of the numbers.
along the column. making a column like this
[2, 0, 1, 0, 0] into [0, 0, 0, 2, 1]

Many thanks

Comment: Please don't post pictures when you could just as easily post the code for the two arrays so that others could cut/paste to quickly check a solution. Not a huge deal for these small arrays, but as a general principle, please don't post pictures of code or data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stable argsort on the binarized array

```
# make example
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> 
>>> exmpl = sparse.random(5,4,0.5).A
>>> 
>>> exmpl
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.61062949, 0.        ],
       [0.85030071, 0.81443545, 0.        , 0.82208658],
       [0.0258324 , 0.77722165, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.4879589 , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.28429359, 0.59514095, 0.06782943]])

# sort it
>>> exmpl[(exmpl!=0).argsort(0,kind="stable"),np.arange(4)]
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.81443545, 0.61062949, 0.        ],
       [0.85030071, 0.77722165, 0.4879589 , 0.82208658],
       [0.0258324 , 0.28429359, 0.59514095, 0.06782943]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort along the columns.

`np.sort(matrix, axis=0)`

Comment: thank you! but I must keep the original order, do you have any idea for that?

Comment: run this code first. it gives the output as you have shown in after_matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For each column, split the array into nonzero and zero  elements. Then recombine them with the nonzero elements at the end.

```
import numpy as np
column = np.array([1, 0, 2, 0, 0])
n = len(column)

nz = column[np.nonzero(column)] # nonzero elements
ze = np.zeros(n-len(nz)-1) # zeros

new_column = np.array([*ze,*nz]) # combining
```

You can also use np.concatenate([ze,nz]) to recombine them.